# ASP.NET MVC controller binding specific properties on child model with BindAttribute using Include

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Prefix: I don't like this approach, I think that the `Bind` attribute is clunky. That said, I have a complex model. It is in an ASP.NET MVC razor view that uses a partial view.

Ideally I would like to just have the partial view accept a DTO that has only the fields that I would like to bind. For reasons I can't control I don't have that option.

However I have the ability to modify the controller. So, I am trying to use the `Bind` attribute to only allow the properties of the child that I would like to bind.

Here are the parent and child model classes:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public Menu FullMenu { get; set; }
    public KidDTO SubDTO { get; set; }
}

public class KidDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Date { get; set;}
    public string Addr { get; set;}
}
```

Razor parent view (again I would prefer to only pass the smaller DTO that will be used... but I don't have that option):

```
@model Core.ViewModels.Parent

//Other stuff here
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_CreateEdit", Model);}
```

Here's the child view:

```
@model Core.ViewModels.Parent

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateEdit", "Child", new AjaxOptions {  HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group row">
                 <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubDTO.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="button" value="Submit"  />
        </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEdit([Bind(Include="SubDTO.Name")] Parent model)
{
    // check if its Null or Not
    var IsItNull = model.SubDTO.Name;  //<--model.SubDTO.Name is always Null. ? 
    return RedirectToAction($"{ControllerEntity}Manager");
}
```

So, in short If I Bind to the SubDTO by iteslf it has values, but that then allows for binding to the other attributes of the SubModel, which is what I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: did you try to initialize SubDTO in constructor before setting value to it? in Parent class

Comment: Its on the post. The SubDTO.Name is the input value coming in.

Comment: add Constructor in Parent class `SubDTO = new KidDTO();` and try

Comment: I Tried to add Constructor in Parent class and same result SubDTO is Not null it just doesn't have any values.   so Name Is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was Not able to figure how to get the Include to work with Child Models properties. I could only bind the entire child or nothing.. However I was get it to work using the [Bind(Prefix="")] in the controller like so.

Controller.

```
  [HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEdit([Bind(Prefix="SubDTO.Name")] string childName)
{
    // check if its Null or Not
    var IsItNull = childName  //<--UGLY but Appears to work, This is not Ideal.  
    return RedirectToAction($"{ControllerEntity}Manager");
}
```

Like the comments above alludes, I do not consider this to be the best solution for this common situation, but based on my restrictions it currently the only option that I have available.  This can get very very ugly with a lot of properties.

Comment: I was able to bind one or more properties of a child object like you were looking for, thanks to your answer. In your example, the equivalent of two properties (instead of one) would be `[Bind("Name,Addr", Prefix="SubDTO")] KidDTO model`. The last "Prefix" name is important even though Intellisense makes it look like leaving it out correctly identifies a second parameter as the "Prefix" parameter.  This was in ASP.NET Core 3.1. If this works on your end, maybe we could update your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your model to explicitly set what you can bind to at the class level.

```
    public class Parent 
{
    public Menu FullMenu { get; set; }
    public KidDTO SubDTO { get; set; }
}
[Bind(Include = "Name")]
public class KidDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Date { get; set;}
    public string Addr { get; set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEdit(Parent model)
{
    // check if its Null or Not
    var IsItNull = model.SubDTO.Name;   
    return RedirectToAction($"{ControllerEntity}Manager");
}
```

**Form Collection Post**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEdit(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var subDTO = new KidDTO()
        {
            Name = collection["SubDTO.Name"]
        };
        // check if its Null or Not
        var IsItNull = subDTO.Name;
        return RedirectToAction($"{ControllerEntity}Manager");
    }
```

**cshtml change type button to submit**

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

To keep things simple and clean, try creating a separate model just with the Name property.  The drawback using explicit `[Bind]` is that you can now only bind to the Name using the default Model binder so why not just create a new ViewModel to begin with?

Comment: Please read the issue before Answering,  I don' thave the ability to modify anything but the controller.  I just don't,...    Is it possible to modify the Controller to only bind to  a property on a subModel  like so: public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEdit([Bind(Include="SubDTO.Name")] Parent model)

Comment: From you post it wasn't clear that you couldn't modify the Model.  I think your only option at that point is to use the form collection and manual variable assignment.